# Index vs aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of document - events - that have venues/addresses:

```
venue: {
  name: String,
  street: String,
  city: String
  ...
}
```

When the user creates a new event I would like to offer an autocomplete field for the venue - ideally ordered by city if I can determine the user's location beforehand.

I see that Mongo offers a few methods of managing data from simply searching the collection, aggregation etc..  What would be the recommended approach for my situation?

If I index the event collection - when do I need to be concerned about the speed of search?

And for aggregation... I've not used it before but it seems a good fit especially with geo search but I am unclear as to when aggregation occurs. Is this something that is automatically done/populated once I set it up or do I need to run a cron job on this. Examples I am finding are unclear on this.

Would love to hear experiences people have with similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Aggregations](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/aggregation-introduction/) are just a more sophisticated version of a query - just like in SQL you can do `SELECT * from T1` or `SELECT foo, count(*) from T1 GROUP BY foo` so your question about cron jobs isn't really applicable unless you want to query something that's intensive to compute and you want to pre-compute it periodically.

When you [index the fields](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/indexes-introduction/) that you query on, the result is the query will run much faster than an unindexed query - just like in RDBMS if you are familiar with those.

It sounds like you want to make a query based on what the user has already typed in.  If I'm in San Francisco, CA and I started typing "S" in the venue field, presumably you want to run the query `db.venues.find({city:"San Francisco",name:/^S/})` which would mean "venue in the city of San Francisco, name starting with 'S'."

I suspect you should save coordinates so that you can use [geo-spacial search](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/query/#geospatial) features in MongoDB - then you would get matching results sorted by closest to furthest from the coordinates that the user set as their location.

You can do this with a query so I don't see that you need an aggregation but it's possible that you would use aggregation to do various analysis of venues - the same queries are supported there, along with other powerful data manipulation operations.